# Change order/level of plots in Show when PlotLegends is present

Tags: plotting, legending

I have downloaded some data to generate two time series:

```
mydata = FinancialData["SP500", {{2014, 01, 01}, {2016, 12,31}}];
mydata3 = mydata*Sin[2];
DateListPlot[{mydata, mydata3}]
```

[image]

Next, I generate an indicator variable to create a shaded region in my final plot:

```
mydata2 = TimeSeries[Table[0, Length[mydata["Dates"]]], {mydata["Dates"]}];
mydata2 = TimeSeriesInsert[mydata2,Thread[{TimeSeriesWindow[mydata2, {{2015, 01, 01},{2015, 12, 31}}]["Dates"], 1}]];
DateListPlot[mydata2]
```

[image]

Finally, I generate a plot with the two series:

```
 mydataPlot = DateListPlot[{mydata, mydata3},
   PlotLegends -> Placed[SwatchLegend[{"US", "EU"}], {0.07,0.835}]];
mydata2Plot = DateListPlot[TimeSeriesMap[#*10000 + Min[mydata2] &, mydata2],
   Filling -> Bottom,
   FillingStyle -> {1 -> HatchFilling[-Pi/4]},
   PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Red, Thickness[0.00001], Opacity[0.35]},
   InterpolationOrder -> 0];
Show[mydataPlot, mydata2Plot]
```

[image]

I would like to understand how to make the solid lines go over the dashed region. If I just invert the order in show, the formatting is not the desired one:

```
Show[mydata2Plot, mydataPlot]
```

[image]

I have done some research and found this code which works if I remove the line where I specify `PlotLegends` but breaks once I add it:

```
Show[mydata2Plot, Graphics[##], ##2] & @@ mydataPlot
```

How can I solve this problem and keep the legend?

Comment: A easy workaround is to do Show[mydataPlot, mydata2Plot, mydataPlot]

Comment: I have updated my question. I had simplified too much to the point of removing the part that was generating the issue. Your suggestion, while helpful, cannot apply to my case because it would double the legend

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

mydata = FinancialData["SP500", {{2014, 01, 01}, {2016, 12, 31}}];
mydata3 = mydata*Sin[2];

mydata2 = TimeSeries[Table[0, Length[mydata["Dates"]]], {mydata["Dates"]}];
mydata2 = 
  TimeSeriesInsert[mydata2, 
   Thread[{TimeSeriesWindow[mydata2, {{2015, 01, 01}, {2015, 12, 31}}][
      "Dates"], 1}]];

mydataPlot = DateListPlot[{mydata, mydata3}];
mydata2Plot = 
  DateListPlot[TimeSeriesMap[#*10000 + Min[mydata2] &, mydata2], 
   Filling -> Bottom, FillingStyle -> {1 -> HatchFilling[-Pi/4]}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Red, Thickness[0.00001], Opacity[0.35]}, 
   InterpolationOrder -> 0];
```

A simple (albeit inefficient) solution is just to add a second `mydataPlot` to the `Show`. Also, remove the `PlotLegends` from `mydataPlot`, and wrap the `Show` in `Legended`

```
Legended[
 Show[mydataPlot, mydata2Plot, mydataPlot],
 Placed[SwatchLegend[ColorData[97] /@ {1, 2}, {"US", "EU"}], {0.07, 0.835}]]
```

[image]